# Joining Multiple Tables using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I'm needing some help with pulling data from multiple tables ( 3 total ). I know there is the JOIN option, but I'm still having some trouble. Not sure if I can JOIN the tables in one query to get my results. I'll try to explain what I'm doing before I post my attempted code...

I'm trying to make an "Inventory Need" section on my site. I've got an `INVENTORY_PRODUCTS` table where I check to see if the column `UNITSINSTOCK` is less than the `MINLEVEL` qty. Pretty simple. But I also need to check and see if that product is "On Order". To do that I need to check my `INVENTORY_ORDERS` AND `INVENTORY_ORDER_DETAILS` tables.

The status of the order is in the `INVENTORY_ORDERS` table ( if it's `1` or `NULL` ) and then the details for the orders are in `INVENTORY_ORDER_DETAILS`. So I will need the `SUM` for that item if it exists.

My HTML table has the following columns: `Product #, Min, Max, Stock, On Order and Need`.

This is what I'm trying to use:

```
    function get_inventory_below_need($mfctId) {

    $this->db->select('
        INVENTORY_PRODUCTS.ID, INVENTORY_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTNUMBER, INVENTORY_PRODUCTS.MINLEVEL, INVENTORY_PRODUCTS.MAXLEVEL, INVENTORY_PRODUCTS.UNITSINSTOCK,
        SUM(INVENTORY_ORDER_DETAILS.QUANTITY) AS ORDERQTY
    ');
    $this->db->from('INVENTORY_PRODUCTS');
    $this->db->join('INVENTORY_ORDER_DETAILS', 'INVENTORY_ORDER_DETAILS.PRODUCTID = INVENTORY_PRODUCTS.ID', 'INNER');
    $this->db->join('INVENTORY_ORDERS', 'INVENTORY_ORDERs.ID = INVENTORY_ORDER_DETAILS.ORDERID', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->where('INVENTORY_PRODUCTS.MANUFACTURERID', $mfctId);
    $this->db->where('INVENTORY_ORDERS.STATUS != 9');
    $this->db->where('INVENTORY_PRODUCTS.UNITSINSTOCK < INVENTORY_PRODUCTS.MINLEVEL');
    $this->db->group_by('INVENTORY_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTNUMBER');
    $this->db->order_by("INVENTORY_PRODUCTS.PRODUCTNUMBER", "asc");

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result();
}
```

The problem is it's only displaying items that have a stock level below the min level AND are currently being ordered. But I've got some products that are below min level and not being ordered.

Hope all this makes sense!

Comment: If you have access to mysql (either through phpmyadmin or something else), I would suggest writing the query out first to see if you get the proper data and then converting that query into the active record class (if that's what you want to use)

Comment: have you tried without left in `$this->db->join('INVENTORY_ORDERS', 'INVENTORY_ORDERs.ID = INVENTORY_ORDER_DETAILS.ORDERID', 'LEFT');`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->query('enter sql query here');
```

sure you will have to type out the query that you want to use, but it will most likely look nicer and if you are using PHP MyAdmin or have another way to access the database you can test it.